# Iteration WAS working in my script, now I cant get python to iterate - what happened?

Tags: python

Did my python ide break or something?

```
import sys

i = 0
sample = ("this", "is", "Annoying!")

for line in sample:
    print i, line
    i + 1
```

Now gives me...

```
0 this 
0 is 
0 Annoying!
```

I THOUGHT, it would give me:

```
1 this 
2 is 
3 Annoying
```

I had other scripts that I was working on and it they all just broke - they all have the same line number when they print numerous iterations using the for statement - can someone PLEASE tell me what the heck is going on - very frustrated lol... did Python break? Do I need sleep?  What is wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the other answers are correct, this is how you usually do this in python:

```
sample = ("this", "is", "Annoying!")

for i, line in enumerate(sample):
    print i, line
```

The `enumerate` function does exactly what you want: Iterating through your tuple, while at the same time giving you (line) numbers.

Answer (score 7):

You are calculating `i+1` but are not storing the result of that anywhere. Specifically you are not updating `i` to contain the new value. Use `i = i + 1` or `i += 1` instead.

Answer (score 4):

This works just fine for me:

```
>>> import sys
>>> i = 0
>>> sample = ("abc", "def", "ghi")
>>> for line in sample:
...   i = i + 1
...   print i, line
... 
1 abc
2 def
3 ghi
```

Are you sure you're incrementing and storing the value `i`? (Your sample omits this, but in another answer you say you did put `i = i + 1`.) Remember, Python is whitespace-sensitive, so if you did something like this, the result won't be what you expect:

```
>>> for line in sample:
...   print i, line
... i = i + 1 # <-- This is not part of the loop!
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have an indentation problem, that perhaps the i = i + 1 statement is somehow not part of the for-loop.

But Instead of doing your own counter incrementing, better practice is to use enumerate:

```
for i,line in enumerate(sample):
    print i,line
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're doing "i + 1", not "i=i+1"

Answer (score 2):

You're not incrementing the variable `i` in your code, you'd need to do something like:

```
for line in sample:
    i = i + 1
    print i, line
```

Comment: sorry I was doing that - I had that in my script forgot to copy it over, I fixed the pasted code.  Still same problem...

Comment: You're only doing `i + 1`? I guess you still need to assign the new value, like `i = i + 1` :)

Comment: yeah was only doing i + 1, I see why that was not working now.

Also, I was told I could do print i+1, line, but that didn't work either.... what am I doing wrong or does that not work?

Answer (score 2):

The result that you expect would be obtained by using enumerate:

```
sample = ("this", "is", "Annoying!")
for index, line in enumerate(sample):
    print index, line
```

I don't see how the code that you posted ever would have worked in any version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Just step through debugger to see the execution.